Magnesium Bicarbonate Synthesis, How to be Certain of the Moles of CO2 added to Water?
Background Research
Through googling all I find is using chilled sparkling water or carbonating water and then adding a teaspoon of magnesium hydroxide to it.
The problem with these methods is that the moles of carbonic acid (I should say carbon dioxide) are unknown, therefore the solution made could have unreacted magnesium hydroxide.
$$
  \ce{
      Mg(OH)2(s) + 2CO2(g) -> Mg(HCO3)2(aq)
  }
$$
I tried to use carbonic acid in the equation but it was impossible to balance, so I just got this equation online.
Problem
Now if I was to carbonate some water how could I be sure that it contains 2 moles (or a stoichiometrically equivalent amount if that is too much) of carbon dioxide?
Is there a way to do this so the  moles of carbon dioxide added are known accurately?
I can't just drop a known mass of dry ice into water, then seal the container for obvious reasons.

Without excess of CO2, the reaction may not be complete.

Yea I understand which is why I would like to figure out how to find the mass of $\ce{CO2}$ there are many layman videos/articles on this but none are chemistry based (though obviously this is a chemical reaction) and I have a feeling the solution or drink they created in the way described in the description (1st paragraph) contains $\ce{Mg(HCO3)2}$

I'd also like to know the mass of CO2 so that I know how much Mg(HCO3)2 has been produced, and I'd use an excess to be on the safe side

Since the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ in soda water is unknown, here are two ways to get a known quantity of that gas:

Measure the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ in seltzer, e.g., by measuring pressure above the tonic in a known volume and temperature, or by titration using an indicator and $\ce{NaOH}$. The disadvantage is that the concentration of $\ce{CO2}$ likely varies from bottle-to-bottle, and with time (once opened, the gas quickly bubbles out).
Create a known amount of $\ce{CO2}$, e.g., by the reaction $\ce{NaHCO3 + HCl -> NaCl + H2O + CO2 ^}$. Any acid would do, such as vinegar, and an excess does no harm. The disadvantage is that $\ce{CO2}$ is soluble in water, so you'd need to take into account that lost in solution.

However, that's academic. If there's an excess of $\ce{CO2}$ to the milk of Magnesia, you've just wasted some $\ce{CO2}$.

thank you for the reply, I had a read online and this requires lab equipment. Could the pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ be measured at home? I could use the first few containers for measurements (I guess they will have to be opened), I'm fine with an excess of $\ce{CO2}$ just don't want any magnesium hydroxide in the solution. The second option isn't feasible for me unfortunately.

It depends on the pressure. A tire pressure gauge might work for bottled seltzer, or a CO2 cartridge (used in soda siphons, bike tire repair, etc.).

If I use a tire pressure gauge then I'd have to add a nozzle attachment to the bottle I guess, same thing with if I use a $\ce{CO2}$ cartridge to fill the bottle (probably the easiest way) right?

@Nickotine, that's plumbing, not chemistry ;-)

hahaha, I am terrible at the practical side, I'm interested to know how you would go about it if you didn't have lab equipment?

I just seen you can buy a sparkling water machine which has a pressure gauge, many thanks for the idea

The machine is actually very expensive. The cooler the liquid the more gas can be dissolved. I found this equation which I think I can use to calculate the pressure: $C = kP$ where C is the constant proportion of the gas which I can just look up but it's value is at $298K$ and I have 2 missing variable, $k$ henry's constant and $P$ the partial pressure (can I use that for pressure?) so I guess I can't use this equation to calculate the pressure right? I guess being too accurate with the $\ce{CO2}$ doesn't matter as I want that in excess, perhaps just testing the pH is the best way to go.

never mind the value of henry's constant for $\ce{CO2}$ is documented so I can use this equation, I studied chemistry 15 years ago at university, so I'd like to make sure if this equation is applicable for my purpose (very rusty).
